# how to make Nginx use home directory as root

Tags: permissions, nginx

I have set up a local server on my laptop for web development and to check the website I'm working on I should have my code base in */var/www/example.domain* which is not so convenient, I want Nginx to retrieve the files and parse PHP from my home directory, something like */home/projects/test-one/* but if I add this directory to `root` it'll throw me a **502 Bad Gateway** error

here's my configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name _;

    location / {
            root /home/amirreza/Projects/escribir/;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
    }
    location ~* \.php$ {
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
            include         fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

in */etc/nginx/sites-available/default*, I'm on Debian 11

-----------------edit-------------------

I was using fpm but my configuration didn't include it, I changed my sites-available/default to this:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php-fpm.sock;
    }
```

and also there was an issue with file permissions in my home folder, I changed it this way:

1- I added my user to www-data group using `sudo usermod -aG www-data amirreza`

2- and then set the permissions of my code base to 664 (instead of 644) so that I can edit it as well:
`-rw-rw-r--   1 amirreza www-data     22 دسامبر  16 13:19 index.php`

Comment: The user running nginx needs to have read-access to the files it tries to serve.

Comment: rathier, that's an additional consideration, but 502 "Bad gateway" is probably not caused by file access, but by failure to talk to the fastcgi server.

Comment: Is your PHP fastcgi server up and running, Amirreza?

Comment: the issue was a mix of fastcgi and permissions issue, I'll edit my question